# Will dynamically inserted meta tags(by javascript) be detected and picked up by Twitterbot? (twitter photo card)

Tags: php, ajax, api, twitter

Is it possible? Does twitterbot detect and process dynamically inserted meta tags? If not, it would only mean that the meta tags would have to be rendered from server-side script. However, the application i'm working on utilizes hashtag to dynamically change content (ajax). What would be the best and proven approach in this environment?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have tried, TwitterBot crawler does not render javascript.
In my case, I am only generating meta tags for the Twitter Card when the *HTTP_USER_AGENT* is *TwitterBot*.
The code starts with something like this.

```
if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'twitterbot') !== false) {
```

You can check if your code works by testing your url on the Twitter Card Validator.
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/validation/validator

Hope this helped!